# Print arguments of a function using Clang AST

Tags: c++, llvm, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, format-string

I want to get the arguments passed to a function. for example, if I have the call

> printf("%d%d", i, j);

the output should be

> %d%d
> i
> j

I am able to get to function calls using VisitCallExpr() in RecursiveASTVisitor. Also able to get the number of arguments and the argument types. But I don't know how to get the arguments.

```
bool MyRecursiveASTVisitor::VisitCallExpr (clang::CallExpr *E)  
{
    for(int i=0, j=E->getNumArgs(); i<j; i++)
    {
        llvm::errs() << "argType: " << E->getArg(i)->getType().getAsString() << "\n";
    }
    return true;
}
```

Output:

> argType: char *
> argType: int
> argType: int

Please help me getting the arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling E->getArg(i)->getType() - but that is type of argument. Use E->getArg(i) to get Expr* representing value of argument. Then use [printPretty(...)](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Stmt.html#a7b6d8297403170952d84a89867ddbb1b) method to pretty-print it to string, if you need string value.

Comment: Hi martins, your answer was very helpful martins. I didn't know about printPretty(...) function. Now, I am able to print the arguments. Thank You.

Answer (score 13):

your answer was very helpful martins. I didn't know about printPretty(...) function. Now, I am able to print the arguments. below is my code to print the arguments.

```
bool MyRecursiveASTVisitor::VisitCallExpr (clang::CallExpr *E)
{
    clang::LangOptions LangOpts;
    LangOpts.CPlusPlus = true;
    clang::PrintingPolicy Policy(LangOpts);

    for(int i=0, j=E->getNumArgs(); i<j; i++)
    {
        std::string TypeS;
        llvm::raw_string_ostream s(TypeS);
        E->getArg(i)->printPretty(s, 0, Policy);
        llvm::errs() << "arg: " << s.str() << "\n";
    }
    return true;
}
```

and the output looks like this:

```
"%d%d"
i
j
```